# Count data by Date Column in Crystal Report Enterprise

Tags: crystal-reports, report, enterprise

I have to produce such table in the Crystal Report. **I have to find the number of data for each month**

```
Months  No. of Data
Dec-08  5
Jan-09  10
Feb-09  11
```

Currently i have trouble doing a count formula to find the No. of Data for EACH month.
My data now is not grouped by each month and the No. of Data is not counted. Here is what i have now:

```
Months  Data
Dec-08  abc
Dec-08  dbc
Dec-08  gdd
Dec-08  hhf
Jan-09  jhg
Feb-09  jhg
```

Comment: what is the problem in grouping?

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: go to `insert group` and select `Months` from dropdown and click ok